# flutter plugins which has UIWebView APIs

Tags: flutter

received alert from apple ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

and don't know which plugin used UIWebView

my pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  responsive_container: ^0.0.1
  flutter_html: ^0.10.4
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter_pagewise: ^1.2.3
  share: ^0.6.2+1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  flutter_youtube: ^1.1.6
  loader_search_bar: ^1.0.3+3
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.4
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.2
```

which one used UIWebView to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `flutter_facebook_login`. If you know native code you can config it. If not, I would recommend to either use any other way to login with facebook or you can make your app with this plugin only. Yup, it will work for now and Appstore will not remove it. It's deprecated that means it should not be used in future. So, there is a pretty good chance in future the developer of the plugin will update the app with the latest APIs.

Comment: i saw at flutter_facebook_login , facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly; can i change way to login or must remove all plugin !

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understood what you mean. You don't need to remove all plugins just the one which causes the problem.

Comment: do i have to remove all plugin , or can i config it to not use UIWebView